# Anyone know the name of this serif font?

Tags: fonts, font-identification, serif

[image]

Anyone know this font? Or a similar one?

Comment: Hi there - please check these resources, and let us know what you have tried. Saves everybody time. http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/font-identification

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That would be Caslon540 I believe

[Caslon on WIKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caslon), there are more than 65 variants of Caslon Typeface.

[image: Caslon540]

Comment: N letter is the clue

Comment: And the slope of the serifs on Z.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like **Pradell**, image linked below, found via identifont

[image]

Comment: It's certainly close, but not exact. Note that the sample image has serifs that flare quite a bit more.

Comment: I don't see much of a difference, though the image is small and has a drop shadow, so that could be fooling the eye.
I think the ascender on the A seals the deal.

Comment: It's very hard to tell at that resolution. The serifs look bracketed, but that could just be a combination of anti-aliasing, low-res and an almost-eradicated shadow.

Comment: Unless it's customized from Pradell, that's not it. Look at the angles of the serifs on the Z and the serifs are too flat.

Comment: N does not match

Comment: E does not match. The bottom bar is longer in Pradell whereas the top and bottom bar are of equal length in the target font.

Comment: @Dominic Keep trying to notice the small things, trained eyes do the trick! (but don't come and blame me afterwards if you see kerning problems everywhere) :-)